# Prestashop 1.6 How to remove email from guest checkout?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I made small shop using Prestashop 1.6. And I need to simplify a guest checkout.

Need to remove required email from guest checkout but leave it for an account registration.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like something best addressed by contacting support helpline for this product.  It doesn't sound like a programming issue.

Comment: Sadly I don't think that they can help with it. For example, you need to edit cms code  to remove unnecessary fields

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from : /controllers/front/AuthController.php and remove the selected code in pic, That's all

[Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqER.png)

Line 273, code is :

`if (empty($email)) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An email address required.');
        }`